# Problem with cross-referencing subsections in Appendix

Tags: cross-referencing, appendices

I have a problem with cross-referencing subsections in the appendix using the AER-AEA document class. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[AER]{AEA}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}

\begin{document}

\begin{proposition}\label{Prop1}
Interesting proposition.
\end{proposition}

Proof of Proposition~\ref{Prop1} is in Appendix~\ref{appendix_A1}.\\

\appendix
\section{Appendix}
\subsection{Proof of Proposition~\ref{Prop1}}\label{appendix_A1}
Proof is here.

\end{document}
```

This code gives:

Proof of Proposition 1 is in Appendix A.A1.

But I would like to get:

Proof of Proposition 1 is in Appendix A1.

Comment: Where is this AEA document class from?

Comment: More to the point, does it support chapters?  Try printing \thechapter or \thesection or \thesubsection in the appendix.

Comment: It is the LaTeX style for The American Economic Review journal of the American Economic Association . (http://www.aeaweb.org/)

Comment: When I put \thesubsection after "Proof is here." I get "A1" on the pdf output.

Comment: In the aux file you should find `\newlabel{appendix_A1}{{A1}{1}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [AEA class](https://www.aeaweb.org/content/file?id=57)

does

```
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection\@arabic\c@subsection}
```

in the `\appendix` command, i.e. prepending with `\thesection`, which is `\@Alph\c@section` effectively.

The reference format `\p@subsection` can be changed to use `\theproposition` only, by removing specific code for `subsection`.

Please note that journal editors might reject this change.

Edit: Some explanations

The macro `\g@addto@macro` adds additional code to an existing macro code, so `\g@addto@macro{\appendix}{foo}` would lead to printing `foo` if `\appendix` has been used.

Since this `\g@addto@macro` is a macro with `@` - letter in its name, the `\makeatletter...\makeatother` macro pair is needed to allow `@` in macro names.

The `\AtBeginDocument` hook 'guarantees' that our local changes to `\appendix` are done at the beginning of the document, after all other `\AtBeginDocument` - hooks that are provided by the class or the packages, so our changes are the last in this chain of commands.

```
\documentclass[AER]{AEA}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}


\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
\g@addto@macro{\appendix}{\renewcommand{\p@subsection}{}}
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{proposition}\label{Prop1}
Interesting proposition.
\end{proposition}

Proof of Proposition~\ref{Prop1} is in Appendix~\ref{appendix_A1}.\\

\appendix
\section{Appendix}
\subsection{Proof of Proposition~\ref{Prop1}}\label{appendix_A1}
Proof is here.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! Completely solved my problem! Fingers crossed so that it goes through at the journal. Just for my own education, where could I find any material to help me understand what exactly this bit of code does? \makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
\g@addto@macro{\appendix}{\renewcommand{\p@subsection}{}}
}
\makeatother so that next time I can do it myself? Many thanks again!

Comment: @Lednacek: Added some explanation

Comment: Thank you SO much! This is very clear and extremely helpful!

Comment: @Lednacek: Forgot to mention the source of such material: Well, reading the LaTeX core code in `latex.ltx` and the class files helps a lot, but of course, the learning curve is steep (it was and sometimes still is for me too). ... and you find some 'dirty' tricks here on TeX.SE of course as well ;-)